# how to use StringBuilder on telegram bot with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, bots, telegram

I have create one API for the sending image with caption using ASP.NET C# on telegram bot. And I want to send link in the caption with create <a /> tag. But I have tried using `StringBuilder` to print the whole line same on telegram bot. I don't know how can do that. Any one know where is my problem in the code?

Here this is my API:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void SendCasesOnTelegramBot()
{            
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = DataAccess.ExecuteDataset(Setting.ConnectionString(), "GetPostForTelegramBot");
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0] != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                var Image = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Url"].ToString();
                byte[] imageData = null;
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                imageData = webClient.DownloadData(Image);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<a href='https://t.me/abc'>abc</a>"); // this is my tag.i want to juts print abc in the caption and i am click on abc work like link.                       
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(".");
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(".");
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);                   
                Bot.SendPhotoAsync("@abc", new FileToSend(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Url"].ToString(), ms), sb.ToString());                      
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
    }
}
```

Here this is my image on telegram bot I have sent:

[image]

see in the image I have print same line but I don't want it like this. I want just print "**abc**" and click on abc work like link. Please help me and give some idea.

Comment: If your `Bot.SendPhotoAsync()` method is `async`, you should `await` it (and make this action `async` as well). You cal also reuse your `Image` variable in the call instead of digging into your dataset again.

Comment: but my question is on link to set in the caption so can you please give me hint on that

Comment: I can't help you with your question, that's why I added a comment. But I can give you some advice with general good practice in programming, which you seem to need.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as if the bot API does not understand HTML tags when calling `sendPhoto`. If you want to use markup, you might have to send a subsequent [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) with the `parseMode` set to "*HTML*"

Comment: you mean i want to sent first photo and then after send message with parseMode??

Comment: Pretty much, unless you don't mind sending a non-markup URL. Check the [API Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api); it should give you details about limitations.

Comment: ok thanks for the your reply asap. and give me some idea about it.otherwise  i will just spent time on searching how can do how can do. but again thank you so mucj

Comment: Hi i have one question so can you please help me i want to uplaod video on telegram bot so how can do that? please give me hint i have ask question also on here

Comment: I have never used Telegram, or plan to use it. I just read the [api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideo) documentation which I suggest you also do as a first point of call as I have explained in my comment above.